# Number of vacuously transitive relations

Tags: combinatorics, relations

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is vacuously transitive if it is transitive but there do not exist ordered pairs such as $(x,y)$,$(y,z)$,$(x,z)$ .

If $A$ has $n$ elements, what is the number of such relations on $A$?

I tried for some small sets. For the null set, it is $1$. For the singleton, it is $2$.

OEIS lists a few more terms [here](https://oeis.org/A003041). It shows the value $7$ for $n=2$. I am not getting $7$ though.

Comment: Please edit to add more context.  Where did you encounter this problem?  Is there any reason to imagine that it has a sensible solution? What is the answer for small $n$?  (Yes, $n=0,1$ are trivial cases...what about $n=2$ or $3$)?

Comment: Did you consider the empty set and relations that don't use all of the elements? For example, $(1,1)$ by itself is a perfectly valid relation on $A$ for $n=2$.

Comment: @John, that gives five relations, and $\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ is a sixth, but what's the seventh?

Comment: Did you get $\{(1,2)\}$ and $\{(2,1)\}$?

Comment: Yeah, where/what is the seventh?

Comment: I am not sure there is a seventh. @lulu Did you try this for $n=2$?

Comment: 1. $\{ \}$
2. $\{(1,1)\}$
3. $\{(1,2)\}$
4. $\{(2,1)\}$
5. $\{(2,2)\}$
6. $\{(1,1),(1,2)\}$
7. $\{(1,1),(2,1)\}$
8. $\{(1,1),(2,2)\}$
9. $\{(2,2),(1,2)\}$
10. $\{(2,2),(2,1)\}$

Comment: $\{(1,2), (1,1)\}$ is transitive, for example. So is the same relation with $(1,2)$ replaced by $(2,1)$

Comment: See above. I am getting ten of them.

Comment: Many of those are transitive. I believe there are only six.

Comment: I believe 6, 7, 9 and 10 are transitive.

Comment: They are all transitive.

Comment: @Ibadul: Your 3. and 4. are isomorphic; 2. and 5. ditto; 7. and 9.; 6. and 10. Sharp is counting up to isomorphism.

Comment: No. 9th is different from 7th.

Comment: @JohnDouma  I did not.  I'm not entirely sure what count is intended...That is, are isomorphic relations equivalent or not?

Comment: I didn't think so but @JukkaKohonen says yes.

Comment: @JohnDouma  I'd say you were more likely to get a sensible enumeration of the isomorphism classes, but who knows?  As a rule, none of these counts have very pleasant answers but I'm sure there are some instances that work out nicely.

Comment: Isomorphism is not mentioned in the question here, nor in the OEIS entry (should be improved), but the cited paper by Sharp says "We  wish to count isomorphism classes".

Comment: @JukkaKohonen  It seems clear that the OEIS list refers to isomorphism classes, no?  $7$ seems too small otherwise (though I haven't done the work to be sure of that).

Comment: Since the OEIS entry only cites Sharp's paper (and the printed EIS), surely it is using Sharp's definition, i.e. counting isomorphism classes. But it never says anything to that effect. OEIS entries are sometimes vague about isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OEIS entry that you mention has the reference

> H. Sharp, Jr., Enumeration of vacuously transitive relations, Discrete
> Math. 4 (1973), 185-196.

If you follow that up, you find an explicit listing of the relations for $n=2$ and $3$ on page 194. For $n=2$ they are, in matrix notation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&1\end{bmatrix},\\
\begin{bmatrix}0&0 \\ 1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0 \\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
so check which one(s) you may have missed.

### About the definition of *vacuously transitive*

**EDIT** (after comments). Sharp's definition is a bit vague. For completeness here is his definition:

> **Definition 2.1.** A *transitive triple* in a relation is a set of three ordered pairs $\{(s_i,s_j),(s_j,s_k),(s_i,s_k)\}$. A relation is
> called *vacuously transitive* if it is transitive but contains no
> transitive triple.

At face value this seems to disallow self-loops in the graph altogether: for if we have $(a,a)$ in the relation, isn't $T=\{(a,a),(a,a),(a,a)\}$ a transitive triple? Yet Sharp clearly allows self-loops.

After reading the definition several times, I think the key is "a **set** of **three** ordered pairs". The $T$ above is a set of only one ordered pair, so it is not a transitive triple. So loops per se are allowed in a vacuously transitive relation.

However, in the 2-element relation $\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)\}$ we *do* have a transitive triple (the full relation is such a triple!) so *this* is not a vacuously transitive relation.

I have to say the definition could have been clearer.

### About isomorphism

Another thing to note is that Sharp is explicitly counting *isomorphism classes* of the relations (i.e. up to permutation of elements). For example, the second of his relations above is $\{(1,1)\}$. He is not counting $\{(2,2)\}$ separately, because it is isomorphic to the previous (the isomorphism is, of course, $f(1)=2, f(2)=1$).

The OEIS entry [A003041](https://oeis.org/A003041) does not explicitly say "isomorphism", but since the numbers are from Sharp's paper and that is the only source cited (besides the printed Encyclopedia), we can deduce that the OEIS entry is meant to be about isomorphism classes. I will try to refine the entry. (UPDATE: The OEIS entry is now better.)

Comment: I know that. But I don't understand why the last two are included.

Comment: You mean, for example, the last one has transitive triple $(2,2),(2,2),(2,1)$? It seems Sharp's definition of a transitive triple is a bit incomplete; from the solutions it would seem he does not consider consider it a transitive triple if the first or second pair is a loop $(a,a)$. Indeed he separately considers *irreflexive* vac. trans. graphs where loops are disallowed; then $n=2$ has only 2, namely the first and fourth above.

Comment: I suggest mentioning that the count considers isomorphisms as the same relation.

Comment: Just to say,  presumably one wants relations like $(a,a)$ to be vacuously transitive, though one could then protest that $(a,a), (a,a), (a,a)$ constitutes a (forbidden) transitive triple.  In any case, I agree that the rules ought to be spelled out clearly and explicitly.